# java error: message Invalid tld file: see JSP 2.2 specification section 7.3.1 for more details

Tags: java, jsp

when i visit local java tomcat page, the error is follow,please help to check what's wrong with this, thank you

jsp code

```java
<%@ taglib prefix="p" uri="/WEB-INF/classes/tld/pagertag.tld"%>
```

error log:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Invalid tld file: "/WEB-INF/classes/tld/pagertag.tld", see JSP 2.2 specification section 7.3.1 for more details

at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:347)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:154)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:419)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:484)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1421)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
```

Comment: It looks like there's an issue parsing the document. Perhaps you can supply it entirely.

Comment: Make sure the path of .tld file is correct. Usually it will be /WEB-INF/tld/ and NOT /WEB-INF/classes/tld

Comment: I downgrade the tomcat to 7.0.46 , the issue was gone~~~

Comment: Simple reason, behaviour changed in 7.0.70+: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59654

Answer (score 14):

as per documentation

> Tag library descriptor files have names that use the extension .tld,
>   and the extension indicates a tag library descriptor file. When
>   deployed inside a JAR file, the tag library descriptor files must be
>   in the META-INF directory, or a subdirectory of it. When deployed
>   directly into a web application, the tag library descriptor files must
>   always be in the WEB-INF directory, or some subdirectory of it. TLD
>   files should not be placed in /WEB-INF/classes or /WEB-INF/lib, and
>   must not be placed inside /WEB-INF/tags or a subdirectory of it,
>   **unless named  implicit.tld** and intended to configure an implicit tag library with its JSP version and tlib-version.

you can place your tag lib inside WEB-INF/tags with rename implicit.tld

Comment: Thanks for this tip, it worked (renaming to implicit.tld)! This suggets that I'm going to have to do some file renaming to make our applications compliant with the standard if I want to run with newer version of Tomcat...

Comment: Renaming subdirectory from tags to tlds works for me.

Answer (score 9):

In the jsp-2_2

JSP.7.3.1 Identifying Tag Library Descriptors
Tag library descriptor files have names that use the extension .tld, and the
extension indicates a tag library descriptor file. When deployed inside a JAR file,
the tag library descriptor files must be in the META-INF directory, or a subdirectory
of it. When deployed directly into a web application, the tag library descriptor
files must always be in the WEB-INF directory, or some subdirectory of it. TLD
files should not be placed in /WEB-INF/classes or /WEB-INF/lib, and must not be
placed inside /WEB-INF/tags or a subdirectory of it, unless named implicit.tld and
intended to configure an implicit tag library with its JSP version and tlib-version.

the .tld file can't be in classes , lib ,tags folder or subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

As quick solution, you can just copy below two libraries from the lib folder of tomcat 7.0.64 and place it in your project root or if you are using maven then add these two as dependency in your pom.xml file:

jasper.jar
jasper-el.jar

This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is with tomcat version. After changing the tomcat version from tomcat 8 to 7.0.55 it works fine.

Comment: Tomcat 8 enforces the spec where Tomcat 7 does not.