# org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: ServletException

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts2, tomcat7

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.65 in struts2 project, I need to upgrade to version 7.0.70, but it causes problems. The last working version of Tomcat in my application is 7.0.69 - on higher versions (from 7.0.70) the start of the application causes such an errors:

I read the Tomcat 7.0.70 changelog but I did not find anything there, who has the idea what the problem is?

```
SOLUTION:

I had to transfer the * .tld files from WEB-INF/tags/subdirectory to WEB-INF/subdirectory and the application got up. Problem solved.
```

First:

```
13:19:08.402 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer - Error rendering tile
org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: ServletException including path '/resources/layout/Login.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.wrapServletException(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:300) ~[tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:200) ~[tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:179) ~[tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72) ~[tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:84) ~[struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.24.3.jar:2.3.24.3]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:606) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105) [struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.24.3.jar:2.3.24.3]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:191) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:372) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:276) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:168) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:140) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.comarch.clm.backoffice.BackOfficeInterceptor.processActionMethod(BackOfficeInterceptor.java:223) [clm-backoffice-web-5.3.9.1-classes.jar:?]
    at com.comarch.clm.backoffice.BackOfficeInterceptor.intercept(BackOfficeInterceptor.java:122) [clm-backoffice-web-5.3.9.1-classes.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ScopeInterceptor.intercept(ScopeInterceptor.java:431) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) [xwork-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:575) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) [struts2-core-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:40002) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /resources/themes/crm_blue/Login.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) Invalid tld file: "/WEB-INF/tags/clmext/privilege.tld", see JSP 2.2 specification section 7.3.1 for more details
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:333) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:366) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:476) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1421) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.__compile(Compiler.java:374) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:41002) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:40001) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:603) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:542) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:955) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jsp.resources.layout.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:122) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:40001) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339) ~[jasper.jar:7.0.70]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.70]
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198) ~[tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    ... 82 more
```

Comment: See the error cause about halfway down the stack.:
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /resources/themes/crm_blue/Login.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) Invalid tld file: "/WEB-INF/tags/clmext/privilege.tld", see JSP 2.2 specification section 7.3.1 for more details    .

Per the change log: 
fix 59654: Enforce the requirements of section 7.3.1 of the JSP specification regarding the permitted locations for TLD files....

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593625/java-error-message-invalid-tld-file-see-jsp-2-2-specification-section-7-3-1-fo/39264879)

Answer (score 0):

I had to transfer the * .tld files from WEB-INF/tags/subdirectory to WEB-INF/subdirectory and the application got up. Problem solved.